# Player does not stop when colliding with block

Tags: c#, collision

I'm trying to make it so my player comes to a complete halt when he hits a block, but can become unstuck if he presses a certain key(s). Example: Player is going down and hits a block. He stops, but if presses W, A, or D, he can move up, left, or right. Here's what I currently have for the code.

In this case, sp means speed, blocksp means his speed when he is being blocked. (This.Sprite), in this case, is referring to the block that stops him.

```
        bool Blocked = false;
        float Bottom = -32;
        float Left = -32;
        float Right = This.Sprite.GetWidth() - 32;
        float Top = This.Sprite.GetHeight() - 32;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        float sp = 1.59f;
        float blocksp = 0.00f;
        Sprite Player = This.Game.FindSprite("GuySprite");
        if (This.Sprite.CollisionWithSprite("GuySprite") != null)
        {

            if (Player.Position.Y > Top)
            {
                Blocked = true;
                Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * blocksp;
                Player.Animation = 0;
                if (This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.W) || This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.A) || This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.D))
                {
                    Blocked = false;
                    Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * sp;
                    Player.Position.Y -= 0.85f;
                }
            }
            if (Player.Position.Y < Bottom)
            {
                Blocked = true;
                Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * blocksp;
                Player.Animation = 0;
                if (This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.S) || This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.A) || This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.D))
                {
                    Blocked = false;
                    Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * sp;
                    Player.Position.Y += 0.85f;
                }
            }
            if (Player.Position.Y < Right)
            {
                Blocked = true;
                Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * blocksp;
                Player.Animation = 0;
                if (This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.S) || This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.A) || This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.W))
                {
                    Blocked = false;
                    Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * sp;
                    Player.Position.Y -= 0.85f;
                }
            }
            if (Player.Position.Y > Left)
            {
                Blocked = true;
                Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * blocksp;
                Player.Animation = 0;
                if (This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.S) || This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.W) || This.Game.IsPressed(InputKey.D))
                {
                    Blocked = false;
                    Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * sp;
                    Player.Position.X += 0.85f;
                }
            }
        }
```

Currently, if my player touches any side of the block and continues his movement that the block stops, the player will move in an erratic direction and does not stop at the block. Any ideas?

Comment: Which bit of code actually checks the collision against a block?

Comment: Should be this one `if (This.Sprite.CollisionWithSprite("GuySprite") != null) `

Comment: What do you get the player velocity as when the condition is true?

Comment: You should really explain what you are doing. For example are those normal screen coordinates? Or why are Bottom/Left/Top/Right considered as constants. They only depend on the width. Where does the Position of the Block appear ?

Comment: @Shaks : The velocity when Blocked == false is                     `Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * sp;`.

Comment: @Infiltator : This is what should check collision with the block. This is code for a behavior that I have attached to the block. If this clears anything up, `Sprite Player = This.Game.FindSprite("GuySprite") if (This.Sprite.CollisionWithSprite("GuySprite") != null)...` is checking for collision, I believe.

Comment: @lorenzalbert Now that I think of it, using -32 as a constant for Bottom and Left doesn't make much sense. Not sure how I would approach that though. Normal screen coordinates? Not sure what you mean exactly. In my Level.cs class I have this attached as a behavior for the block and its position is (250, 250).

Comment: I edit my post to help you a little more ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

Ok [image: here is the picture.]

The player is running towards the block so he'll hit the left side in the next frames.
So that the following condition ll be true.

```
if (This.Sprite.CollisionWithSprite("GuySprite") != null)
```

Now you have to implement a method to find out which side the player collided with.
Actually your code is confusing me since:

```
Player.Velocity = new Point2D(x, y) * ...;
```

will always be the zero vector because x = y = 0

I'd do it like this :

```
float xDistance=0f, yDistance=0f;//this ll be explained later on
If(Player.Velocity.X > 0) //he is running to the right so he can hit the left side
     xDistance=mayHitLeft();
Else If(Player.Velocity.X < 0)
     xDistance=mayHitRight();
If(Player.Velocity.Y > 0) //In my case positive Y means downwards so can hit top
     yDistance=mayHitTop();
Else If(Player.Velocity.Y < 0)
     yDistance=mayHitBot();
```

Now we have to find out if the player hit the bot/top edge or the left/right edge or maybe both.
let's assume he is falling and was running to the right before.
so `Player.Velocity.X > 0` and `Player.Velocity.Y > 0`
This means the function `mayHitLeft();` and `mayHitTop();`
 will be called.
I don't know how the `collisionWithSprite` function works.
But as always we take the worst case [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DNMW.png) blue is the block and orange the player.
This is the frame before hitting and no collision was detected by now. so in the next frame both functions would detect a collision but which is the right one. As we see it is colliding with the top. So how to detec the right one? Therefore we use the distance or let's say  how much overlapping we have in which direction. So less overlap is the right one.

So both functions return a double. Let's look at the `mayHitTop()` function

```
private float mayhitTop()
    {
        //remember that the y coordinate goes downwards so we have to add
        float playersBotCoordinate = Player.Position.Y + Player.Sprite.Height;
        //the y position is the top so nothing to change
        float blocksTopCoordinate = Block.Position.Y;
        hitTop=true; //this is a global variable you have 1 for each direction
        return Math.Abs(playersBotCoordinate - blocksTopCoordinate);
    }
```

So we have set the `xDistance` and `yDistance` and we know that it will hit the top or left.

Now we have to compare everything

```
// this means there could be 2 sides like our case that can be ths possible collision edge
if((hitLeft || hitRight) && (hitTop || hitBot))
{ 
   //we hit the left or right side
   if(xDistance<yDisante)
   {
      Player.Velocity.X = 0;
   }
   //we hit top or bottom
   else
   {         
      Player.Velocity.Y=0;
   }
}
else
{
    if(hitLeft || hitRight)...

}
```

Maybe you have to unstuck the player. Otherwise I think there could be some problems.

So I just wrote it without any template. Don't know if there are any Syntax mistakes. but this shall only give you an overview how to do it ´we can expect this to be pseudocode ;)

Hope it'll help you at least a little.

### Old

Ehhhh you are comparing the player position.Y with right and left 
this should be the X coordinate if I understood the code ;)

```
 if (Player.Position.Y < Right)
```

and

```
if (Player.Position.Y > Left)
```